# Android Room `Insert` - how do I verify by comparing object strings that I won't enter the same object?

Tags: android, entity, sql-insert, android-room, dao

I have the following Room entity -

```java
@Entity(tableName = "recent_search_table")
public class RecentSearchModel {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int ID;

    private String query;

    public RecentSearchModel(){

    }

    public RecentSearchModel(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RecentSearchModel{" +
                "query='" + query + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof RecentSearchModel)
            return this.query.equalsIgnoreCase(((RecentSearchModel) obj).query);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the following DAO -

```java
@Dao
public interface RecentSearchDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insert(RecentSearchModel model);

    @Update
    void update(RecentSearchModel model);

    @Delete
    void delete(RecentSearchModel model);

    @Query("select * from recent_search_table")
    LiveData<List<RecentSearchModel>> getRecentSearchList();

}
```

What happens right now is that I get the same objects written again and again in my Room DB. I want the DAO to prevent adding the same object by actually comparing their `query` parameter, using the `equals()` method I have build in my entity class. As you can see, I have added `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)` which does...nothing. I still see duplicate values.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I have same problem, annotating OnConflict didn't worked also for me

Comment: I don't think there is any way to use the `equals()` method with Room Insert. The hacking way is retrieve all data & check if it contains the entity in the db using `List.contains(itemToInsert)` in a background thread. If it doesn't exists then call insert.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Entity(indices = arrayOf(Index(value = ["query"], unique = true)))
data class RecentSearchModel(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "query") val query: String
)
```

Once you mark your column as unique, you can use `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)`

For Java,

```
 @Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"query"}, unique = true)})
```

Comment: The Conflict strategy works also with unique keys ? Not only primary keys ? If so,  @Alon Shlider this answer is what you need

Comment: how can I replace `arrayOf`? I am using Java not Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

we can use the `indices` annotation in the `Entity`, in that we can define which column as the unique.

```
@Entity(tableName = "test",indices = [Index(value = ["account"],unique = true)])
data class EmailUser(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
@ColumnInfo(name = "account") val account: String,
```

here is the explanation

> >
>   Unique indexes are indexes that help maintain data integrity by ensuring that no two rows of data in a table have identical key values. When you create a unique index for an existing table with data, values in the columns or expressions that comprise the index key are checked for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if room uses the entity's `equal` method to find conflicts but i think you can solve your problem by making the `query` the primary key of your table and remove `id`.

```
@Entity(tableName = "recent_search_table")
public class RecentSearchModel {

@PrimaryKey
private String query;

public RecentSearchModel(){

}

public RecentSearchModel(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public String getQuery() {
    return query;
}

public void setQuery(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RecentSearchModel{" +
            "query='" + query + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof RecentSearchModel)
        return this.query.equalsIgnoreCase(((RecentSearchModel) obj).query);
    return false;
}
}
```